# Chrome extension : How to get / detect click events on any page or any where. just like Google Dictionary Plugin does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

[inspired from Google dictionary plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY6Pm.png)

Chrome extension : How to get / detect click events on any page or any where. just like Google Dictionary Plugin does?

eg. click on a table or a form etc.

Here is the code ,

```
$(".myTable").on('click', 'tr', function () {
var trValue = $(this).attr('value');
var tdValue = $(this).children('td').map(function (index, val) {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();
console.log(tdValue);});
```

Comment: what u have done so far?

Comment: The below code is for getting data from a table. my requirement is ,
I should be able to get data from any table of any page in any tab.

$(".myTable").on('click', 'tr', function () {
 var trValue = $(this).attr('value');
 var tdValue = $(this).children('td').map(function (index, val) {
   return $(this).text();
  }).toArray();
 //alert(tdValue);
});*/

Comment: @K.Karthik, hi, if my answer has helped, please consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), remember to set `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` in manifest.json, it means you content script will be injected into every page.

In your content script, you can listen to click event and do what you want

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Do what you want with click event
}, false);
```