# How to register an event listener to the whole window in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

I am trying to register a mouse click event for the whole window in my chrome extension. Ie, I am running my extension pop up in a tab, but when I click in any other tab I want that the click event is captured.

I'm trying to do that using a content script, "eventsCapturer.js", but it seams that it is not working, since when the mouse is clicked, it should open a new tab, but it only open when I click on my tab where the extension is running.

You can see it in this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6_PAxZyjBjojcuIfVpcWpdfTO91jNoa/view?usp=sharing

This technique was recomended in these posts:

- [Chrome extension : How to get / detect click events on any page or any where. just like Google Dictionary Plugin does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788867/chrome-extension-how-to-get-detect-click-events-on-any-page-or-any-where-ju)
- [Click event on chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792504/click-event-on-chrome-extension)

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Traffic Capturer",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Lucas Pletsch",

"action": {
    "default_title": "Traffic Capturer",
    "default_icon": "icone.jpg",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},
"description": "Reads the navigation data",

"content_scrips": [
    {
    "matches": ["https://*/"],
    "js": ["./js/eventsCapturer.js"]
    }
],

"host_permissions": ["https://*/"],
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "scripting",
    "tabs"
 ]
```

}

And here's my content script ./js/eventsCapturer.js:

```
function addClickListener() {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Clicou em alguma parte da tela')
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com"}, ()=>console.log("Janela aberta"))
    })
}
```

I tried also use **window.addEventListener** intead of document.addEventListener, but it did not work too.

**Obs:** If I click on my popup, the click event is not triggered as well...

**In case you want to test it,** here's my popup, that loads another html in another tab when you click on the button "Initialize Navigation Capture". As I said, in this newly opened tab the mouse clicks are captured perfectly, and the google new tabs are opened, but only in this tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Navigation Capturer</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="initializer">Initialize Navigation Capture</button>
</body>
<script src='./js/capturerInitializer.js'></script> 
</html>
```

And here's **capturerInitializer.js:**

```
var timer
const initializerButton = document.querySelector('#initializer')


initializerButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    initializeCapturerInNewTab()
})


async function initializeCapturerInNewTab() {
    const tab = chrome.tabs.create({
        url: '../html_components/controls.html'
    })
    return tab
}
```

And this is the html of the **new tab that my extension popup creates**, where the mouse click works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Navigation Capturer</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <span>hi</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs. You can use window.open. 2) Add `true` as a third parameter for addEventListener.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, but I included chrome.tab.create only for test reasons, I don't want to open one. I just wanted to capture events from the window where the extension is running...

Comment: @wOxxOm anyway, I replaced document in the event listener by window, and set the third parameter as 'true', and it stills doesn't work:
function addClickListener() {
    window.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Clicou em alguma parte da tela')
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com"}, ()=>console.log("Janela aberta"))
    }, true)
}

Comment: I also added this config to the script in manifest: "run_at": "document_start", and listened to the mousedown event, as you suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605898/ensure-click-event-is-seen-by-the-content-script

Comment: Add `*` to the end of your `matches` string. Better yet, use `*://*/*` to match http as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm it did not work :(
 "content_scrips": [
        {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "js": ["./js/eventsCapturer.js"]
        }
    ],

Comment: I thoght also that the content script is being loaded in every page of the window, but the document.evenListener is what is not working .If this was true, a console.log should print something in each console... However, it did not work. only for the tab created by the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added a video showing the execution of the extension: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6_PAxZyjBjojcuIfVpcWpdfTO91jNoa/view?usp=sharing